# Does Firebase Auth Log me out when I use the reload function?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I used the firebase phone auth, after verification, I want to update the logged in users profile detials. So I wrote a cloud function to do that and then call the `user.reload()` method after the function returned a response. But to my surprise my app gets logged out with this on my console:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-token-expired] The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.

I did some research and I found out it was a security measure, so I had to re-authenticate the user.

This is what I did:

```
 Future<Response> updateUserprofile({context, name, email}) async{

    User _user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    Response response = Response(success: false);
    Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context, listen: false).loading = true;

    try{
      HttpsCallableResult functionResponse  = await createUser.call({'displayName': name, 'email':email});
      response.success = functionResponse.data['success'];
      response.message = functionResponse.data['message'];
      
      _user.reload();

      AuthCredential credential = AuthCredential(providerId: PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, signInMethod: PhoneAuthProvider.PHONE_SIGN_IN_METHOD);
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);

      Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context, listen: false).loading = false;

      return response;
    }catch(e){
      Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context, listen: false).loading = false;
      response.message = e.message;
      return response;
    }
  }
```

but I still get the same error on my console:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-token-expired] The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the user's email. This invalidates the Firebase ID token, as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions.

It seems to be the expected behaviour as also pointed out here: [Firebase Auth - After updating the user's email, Firebase Auth logs out the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283978/firebase-auth-after-updating-the-users-email-firebase-auth-logs-out-the-user). I see that's what you're trying to do as well?

If `user.reload()` returns that exception, than it still does if you call it before:

```
AuthCredential credential = AuthCredential(providerId: PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, signInMethod: PhoneAuthProvider.PHONE_SIGN_IN_METHOD);
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
```

Maybe you should re-authenticate before you reload the user?

---

One other thing I note is that you use `createUser.call`. Since you are updating the credentials of an existing user, why not use `updateUser` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user)?

Comment: I re-authenticated the user before reloading and it kind of worked for the first time but it doesn't work anymore. I still get the same issue